# record page LDS not being refreshed after apex call-back

Tags: lightning-web-components, callback, ui-record-api

We're working on a custom datatable inside a quote recordpage. Such datatable, shows a list of QuoteLineItems that the user can insert/update/delete from the component itself.
Now, since we made the GrandTotal visible on the top of the record page and on the right as per picture, we used to update it calling the "getRecordNotifyChange" method in the insert/update/delete callbacks.
Recently, we noticed that moving to the newer one "notifyRecordUpdateAvailable" since summer '23, LDS stopped updating. Sometimes we noticed that after reloading the page (F5), the grand total wouldn't update either.

During our troubleshooting, we tried stopping the front-end execution right after the apex call with a breakpoint on devtools, confirmed that the quote GrandTotal was updated (we used the Salesforce Inspector) and then fired the notifyRecordUpdateAvailable method but still, the GrandTotal in the page wasn't updating.

[image]

and here's the snipped we're working with:

```
updateLineItems(records){
    this.draftValues = [];
    updateProducts({
        productList: records
    }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.error){
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Prodotto modificato',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            this.initialize();
        } else {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'C\'è stato un errore durante la modifica dei prodotti',
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
            console.log('error', true);
            console.log('errorMessage', response.errorMessage);
            console.log('errorStackTraceString', response.errorStackTraceString);
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error',
                message: 'C\'è stato un errore durante la modifica dei prodotti',
                variant: 'error'
            })
        );
        console.log(error);
    }).finally(() => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.updateQuoteTotals();
    })
}

 updateQuoteTotals(){
    notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[notifyRecordUpdateAvailable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_notify_record_update) returns a promise, you need to use async await for this to work properly. Make sure to pass correct `recordId` to that function:

```js
async updateLineItems(records){
    // existing code
    }).finally(() => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        await notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
    })
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: await seems to be not working there inside the finally() as it's not an async function.
We kinda tried to change it to something like this 
`async updateQuoteTotals(){
        await notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
    }`
and invoce the updateQuoteTotals() like in the snippet in the answer, but still, no changes detected.

Comment: Where is the method `updateQuoteTotals` called from? if you call this from another method, you need to use `async` in callee method again and `await updateQuoteTotals`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it without `async`, which results in a cleaner code:

```
updateProducts({
    productList: records
})
    .then((response) => {
        //...
        return notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{ recordId: this.recordId }]);
    }
    .then(() => {
        // this can be skipped
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        //...
    })
```

Returning the notifyRecordUpdateAvailable's promise in from the first then allows you to chain promises and handle the results in 2nd then. You can skip the second then and just continue with `catch()` and `finally()`